# Unable to locate package

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, installation, package

I am trying to enter `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev` to install OpenCV on ubuntu but I keep getting the errors:

`Unable to locate package libswcale-dev` 
and 
`Unable to locate package libv4l-dev`

Comment: I am also getting erros for ```sudo apt-get install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev```

Comment: Then its simple...  The version of Ubuntu that you're using doesn't have this in the repos that it has available.  The easiest option is to pull down the .rpm itself and install it, or find a repo that has this package and add the repo to the list of repos you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get update`

If no result show your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, please.

Comment: No fix, here is my sources.list: ```deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main     # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main```

Comment: Now I get ```Package libv4l-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libv4l-dev' has no installation candidate```

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/pt/bionic/amd64/libv4l-dev/download